# Creating an array of all objects of a class

Tags: arrays, swift, class, tableview

Is there a way of creating an array of all colour objects created? So that every time a new colour is added, it is also automatically added to the array?

```
class Colours {
    var colourName: String
    var colourShades: [String?]


    init(colourName: String, colourShades: [String?]) {
        self.colourName = colourName
        self.colourShades = colourShades
    }


}

var red = Colours(colourName: "Red", colourShades: ["Crimson", "Cherry", "Rose"])


var blue = Colours(colourName: "blue", colourShades:["Ice", "Baby", "Royal"])
```

To give some context I am attempting to develop an app for IOS which includes a table of colours. Then when a user clicks on a colour it will take them to another table which has shades of that colour.

I want the array of colours so that I can automatically fill in the rows of the table, and then when a user adds a new colour it will automatically add a new row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a static array defined in `Colours` to hold all colours that have been created.  You can access this array as `Colours.allColours` from anywhere in your app.

Create a protocol called `ColourWatcher` and create a `static` `delegate` on `Colours` for a class that will be notified when a colour is added.

Have your tableView implement `ColourWatcher` and add itself as the `delegate`.  Then, when a colour is added, the method `newColourAdded` will be called in your `TableViewController` and you can reload the data.

Also, I would recommend making the array of colour shades just be `[String]` instead of using optionals.  An empty array will signify that you have no shades.

```
protocol ColourWatcher: class {
    func newColourAdded(colour: Colour)
}

class Colours {
    static var allColours: [Colours] = []
    static weak var delegate: ColourWatcher?

    var colourName: String
    var colourShades: [String]

    init(colourName: String, colourShades: [String]) {
        self.colourName = colourName
        self.colourShades = colourShades
        Colours.allColours.append(self)
        Colours.delegate?.newColourAdded(colour: self)
    }
}

class MyTableViewController: UIViewController, ColourWatcher {

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Colours.delegate = self
    }

    func newColourAdded(colour: Colour) {
        // reload table view or just insert a new row
        // using the passed in colour
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a massive help. I'm getting the following error in my tableView function:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
    IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: 
    indexPath)
        
            cell.textLabel?.text = Colours.allColours[indexPath.row]
        
        
            return cell
        }

Error is cannot assign value of type 'Colours' to type 'String?'. 

Also it only worked when I changed Colour to Colours in  newColourAdded func, that right?

Comment: `Colour` vs. `Colours` was just a typo.  Although your class represents just a single colour, so it should probably be named `Colour`.  Try `cell.textLabel?.text = Colours.allColours[indexPath.row].colourName`.

Comment: That got rid of the error, I'll remember that in future. I now have no errors but the table displays empty, even though I have added an object to the class. I've added the number of rows and the content of the rows in the TableController - without error using the regular format. Is there something I'm missing? Sorry to be a pain I'm quite new to this and struggling to get my head around it!

Comment: You should be returning `Colours.allColours.count` for `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Comment: That is what I have, but still empty. No matter what I do the table remains empty. I've been trying everything I can think of but it doesn't appear to be making any difference :/ Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Describe the flow of your app.  How many ViewControllers are there?  How are new colors added?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of creating an array of all colour objects created? So
>   that every time a new colour is added, it is also automatically added
>   to the array?

You can declare one array in your class and append like this

```
lazy var colorList = {
  Colours()
}()
```

> I want the array of colours so that I can automatically fill in the
>   rows of the table, and then when a user adds a new colour it will
>   automatically add a new row.

```
func addColor() {
   colorList.append(Colours(colourName: "Red", colourShades: 
   ["Crimson", "Cherry", "Rose"]))
   colorList.append(Colours(colourName: "blue", colourShades:["Ice", 
   "Baby", "Royal"]))
}
```

once you invoke the above method when add the color then refresh the table to appear the new color information on your table row.

> To give some context I am attempting to develop an app for IOS which
>   includes a table of colours. Then when a user clicks on a colour it
>   will take them to another table which has shades of that colour.

Now in your tableView `cellForrowatindexpath` method you just need to access the above `colorlist` array and fetch the `colorname` and display on your table.

And when user tap on the cell then inside your `didSelecteRowAtIndexpath` method load the another class and pass the above `colorList` array information to that class and in order to display the shade of color access the `colourShades` information from the `colorList` array.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you want to preserve a state in the whole application.

The best way for solving your problem is creating a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) instance.

E.g.

```
class ColoursSharedModel {

    static let shared : ColoursSharedModel = ColoursSharedModel()

    var choosenColors : [Colors] = []
    private init() {}
}
```

Later, you should add

```
ColoursSharedModel.shared.choosenColors.append(self)
```

in your Colors' init.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add your own notification name

```
extension NSNotification.Name {

    // 1
    static let NewColourAdded = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NewColourAdded")
}
```

---

2) Set access modifier for the object pool (static variable `all`) as `private(set)`

3) Add an initialized colours to the object pool

4) Post your notification

```
class Colours {

    // 2
    private(set) static var all: [Colours] = []

    var name: String
    var shades: [String]

    init(name: String, shades: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.shades = shades

        // 3
        Colours.all.append(self)

        // 4
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: .NewColourAdded, 
            object: self
        )
    }
}
```

---

#### usage

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self, 
            selector: #selector(self.onNewColourAdded), 
            name: .NewColourAdded, 
            object: nil
        )
    }

    func onNewColourAdded(notification: Notification) {
        guard let newColours = notification.object as? Colours else { 
            return 
        }

        // Do something
    }
}
```